# Why Cron Job does not fire up

Tags: cron

I'm perplexed why a cron job does not fire up, even though a test case fires up.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 11 * * * sh /home/folder/start.sh
30 11 * * * touch testcron.txt
```

I get the file touched, but the start.sh script never seems to fire up. I'm perplexed

Comment: Could be due to execution rights or permissions. If you add the `touch testcron.txt` into the script, does it create the file?

Comment: yes the file is created. I can run the .sh script too, but only manually.

Comment: cron normally sends you emails with output and error output. Have a look at those using `mail`